# directive is not returning an html element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm a bit struggling to get my head around directive where I'm trying to pass in a name and I want the directive to return an `<img>` into a table.

here is how name defined in the controller:

```
$scope.name = 'foo';
```

here is the html

```
<tr>
    <th>status</th>
    <td><icon-selector filterby="name"></icon-selector></td>
</tr>
```

here is the directive

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('iconSelector', function ($compile) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope:{
            filterby:'='
        },

        link: function(scope,element, attrs) {
            console.log(scope.filterby);
            if (scope.filterby === 'foo') {
                   return '<img src="sample.png">';
            }else {
                 return '<p>invalid</p>';
            }
         }
      };
  });
```

So ideally, when the directive process the {{name}} it should look like below in the browser:

```
<tr>
    <th>status</th>
    <td><img src="sample.png"></td>
</tr>
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, a plunker demo would be appreciated.

Comment: Why `foo` leads to `sample.png`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linking function doesn't return an HTML element to replace the element on which the directive is applied. The `link` function is generally used to register event listeners and DOM manipulation. If you want to replace the element, you can do something like this:

```
link: function(scope,element, attrs) {
  console.log(scope.filterby);
  if (scope.filterby === 'foo') {
    element.replaceWith('<img src="sample.png">');
  } else {
    element.replaceWith('<p>invalid</p>');
  }
}
```

Comment: I've included 'scope.$watch' so that it's called if $scope.name changes but it's only executed once. Is there a way to make the direct link function being called on update. Now it only gets updated when I refresh the browser if the value of name changes dynamically. Can you help me Brenan. Cheers

Comment: What does your watch look like? Where are you changing $scope.name?

Answer (score 1):

Or you can do that in this way:

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.directive('iconSelector', function($compile) {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: {
      filterby: '@'
    },
    template: "<img ng-if='condition' src='{{url}}'/ ><p ng-if='!condition'>invalid</p>",
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {

      scope.condition = scope.filterby == "foo";


      scope.url = 'http://www.saturn.dti.ne.jp/npaka/android/HelloGL10_5/sample.png';
    }
  };
});
app.controller('firstCtrl', function($scope) {

});
```

```css
td, th {
border: solid 1px #d2d2d2
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="firstCtrl">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>status</th>
        <td>
          <icon-selector filterby="foo"></icon-selector>
        </td>
        <td>
          <icon-selector filterby="jam"></icon-selector>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

  </div>
</body>
```